# How to disable splash highlight of FlatButton in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, user-interface, dart, flutter

I have a FlatButton. I don't want the splash highlight when the button is clicked. I tried changing the splash colour to transparent, but that didn't work. Here is the code for my FlatButton.

```
Widget button = new Container(
  child: new Container(
    padding: new EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    child: new FlatButton(
      onPressed: () {
        _onClickSignInButton();
      },
      splashColor: Colors.transparent,
      child: new Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          new Image.asset('images/1.0x/button1.png',
          ),
          new Text("SIGN IN",
            style: new TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 16.0
              ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: maybe you just want to set `hightlightColor` to `Colors.transparent` too.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

I'd expect an invisible highlight color to do what you want:

```
new FlatButton({
  ...
  splashColor: Colors.transparent,  
  highlightColor: Colors.transparent, // makes highlight invisible too
})
```

Comment: highlightColor is actually the parameter that was missing from the OP's shared code... I also suggested editing the code snippet to make it clear that (invisible) is a comment not part of the code and that commas are necessary

Comment: FlatButton is now deprecated for TextButton.

Comment: This also works on IconButton.

Answer (score 14):

since flatbuton is depreciated and for the new textButton we have something like this.

```
TextButton(
   style: ButtonStyle(
   overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
  (Set<MaterialState> states) {
    if (states.contains(MaterialState.focused))
      return Colors.red;
    if (states.contains(MaterialState.hovered))
        return Colors.green;
    if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed))
        return Colors.blue;
    return null; // Defer to the widget's default.
}),
),
 onPressed: () { },
 child: Text('TextButton with custom overlay colors'),
)
```

Answer (score 9):

`FlatButton` was deprecated in Flutter v1.26 (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FlatButton-class.html).

Use `TextButton` and the `overlayColor` property.

```dart
TextButton(
  style: ButtonStyle(
    overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.transparent)
  )
)
```

Answer (score 4):

**For TextButton:**
To disable the splash and the highlight color

```
TextButton(
    onPressed: () {
      print("onPressed");
    },
    style: ButtonStyle(
      overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
        (Set<MaterialState> states) {
          return Colors.transparent;
        },
      ),
      splashFactory: NoSplash.splashFactory,
    ),
    child: Text(
      'Forgot password?',
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 3):

December 2021:

Per flutter/lib/src/material/button_style.dart line 247, the correct way to do this is:

```
style: TextButton.styleFrom(
  splashFactory: NoSplash.splashFactory,
),
```

```
/// Use [NoSplash.splashFactory] to defeat ink splash rendering. For example:
ElevatedButton(
  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
    splashFactory: NoSplash.splashFactory,
  ),
  onPressed: () { },
  child: Text('No Splash'),
),
```

Comment: This does not change anything on my button as far as I can tell, highlight is still shown.

Comment: I agree with @masus04, this does not work.