# How do I remove Flutter IconButton big padding?

Tags: flutter, button, flutter-layout, flutter-widget, iconbutton

I want to have a row of IconButtons, all next to each other, but there seems to be pretty big padding between the actual icon, and the IconButton limits. I've already set the padding on the button to 0.

This is my component, pretty straightforward:

```
class ActionButtons extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Container(
        color: Colors.lightBlue,
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: new Icon(ScanrIcons.reg),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              padding: new EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: new Icon(Icons.volume_up),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              padding: new EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
              onPressed: () {},
            )
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
}
```

[image]

I want to get rid of most of the light blue space, have my icons start earlier on the left, and closer to each other, but I can't find the way to resize the IconButton itself.

I'm almost sure this space is taken by the button itself, 'cause if I change their alignments to `centerRight` and `centerLeft` they look like this:

[image]

Making the actual icons smaller doesn't help either, the button is still big:

[image]

thanks for the help

Comment: Have you tried making your actual icons larger? It looks like the icon may be centered in, but not filling up, it's space in the icon font glyph.

Comment: use GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {},
            child: new Icon(Icons.volume_up)
          )

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It's not so much that there's a padding there. IconButton is a Material Design widget which follows the spec that tappable objects need to be [at least 48px on each side.](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/8a83d0df7f2eab9d4fb29ca6bef4b7d20070a54e/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/icon_button.dart#L198) You can click into the IconButton implementation from any IDEs.

You can also semi-trivially take the icon_button.dart source-code and make your own IconButton that doesn't follow the Material Design specs since the whole file is just composing other widgets and is just 200 lines that are mostly comments.

Comment: wow, the real answer is hidden deep! Setting the padding & constraints doesn't do anything if you're working with small button sizes -- it still forces this 48px minimum!

Answer (score 306):

Simply pass an empty `BoxConstraints` to the `constraints` property and a padding of zero.

```
IconButton(
    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
    constraints: BoxConstraints(),
)
```

You have to pass the empty constraints because, by default, the IconButton widget assumes a minimum size of 48px.

Comment: padding: EdgeInsets.zero, its working but getting error of constraints: BoxConstraints(),

Comment: I had zeroed out the filling, but the information on `constraints` was more important. thanks.

Comment: I preferred using which was half the space, but enough to not be too tight.  
padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),

Answer (score 102):

Two ways to workaround this issue.

### Still Use IconButton

Wrap the IconButton inside a Container which has a width.

For example:

```dart
Container(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
  width: 30.0, // you can adjust the width as you need
  child: IconButton(
  ),
),
```

### Use GestureDetector instead of IconButton

You can also use GestureDetector instead of IconButton, recommended by Shyju Madathil.

```dart
GestureDetector( onTap: () {}, child: Icon(Icons.volume_up) )
```

Comment: Thanks! This fit in perfectly for me :)

Comment: Perfect ever found

Comment: InkWell if you are trying to mimic a FlatButton

Comment: the hack with the constraints of the `IconButton` is really dope

Comment: **Use IconButton**!

Comment: Wrapping IconButton in a Container is not removing the padding

Comment: The Container with a width did the job for me; thanks!

Answer (score 29):

2023 Solution:

```
IconButton(
  onPressed: () {},
  iconSize: 40.0, // desired size
  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
  constraints: const BoxConstraints(), // override default min size of 48px
  style: const ButtonStyle(
    tapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap, // the '2023' part
  ),
  icon: const Icon(Symbols.arrow_right),
),
```

Comment: i still have small splash, i remove it by add `overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.transparent)` in ButtonStyle. Information from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71136751/9597017)

Answer (score 15):

Wrapping the `IconButton` in a container simply wont work, instead use [ClipRRect](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipRRect-class.html) and add a material Widget with an Inkwell, just make sure to give the `ClipRRect` widget enough border Radius .

```
ClipRRect(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
    child : Material(
        child : InkWell(
            child : Padding(
                padding : const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                child : Icon(
                    Icons.favorite_border,
                    ),
                ),
            onTap : () {},
            ),
        ),
    )
```

Comment: Nice solution, and it made me aware of the ClipRRect widget and family. :)

Answer (score 5):

Instead of removing a padding around an IconButton you could simply use an Icon and wrap it with a GestureDetector or InkWell as

```
GestureDetector(
   ontap:(){}
   child:Icon(...)
);
```

Incase you want the ripple/Ink splash effect as the IconButton provides on click wrap it with an InkWell

```
InkWell(
   splashColor: Colors.red,
   child:Icon(...)
   ontap:(){}
)
```

though the Ink thrown on the Icon in second approach wont be so accurate as for the IconButton, you may need to do some custom implementation for that.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution to get rid of any extra padding, using `InkWell` in place of `IconButton`:

```
Widget backButtonContainer = InkWell(
    child: Container(
      child: const Icon(
        Icons.arrow_upward,
        color: Colors.white,
        size: 35.0,
      ),
    ),
    onTap: () {
      Navigator.of(_context).pop();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar issue trying to render an Icon at the location the user touches the screen. Unfortunately, the `Icon` class wraps your chosen icon in a `SizedBox`.

Reading a little of the Icon class source it turns out that each Icon can be treated as text:

```
Widget iconWidget = RichText(
      overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
      textDirection: textDirection,
      text: TextSpan(
        text: String.fromCharCode(icon.codePoint),
        style: TextStyle(
          inherit: false,
          color: iconColor,
          fontSize: iconSize,
          fontFamily: icon.fontFamily,
          package: icon.fontPackage,
        ),
      ),
    );
```

So, for instance, if I want to render `Icons.details` to indicate where my user just pointed, without any margin, I can do something like this:

```
Widget _pointer = Text(
      String.fromCharCode(Icons.details.codePoint),
      style: TextStyle(
        fontFamily: Icons.details.fontFamily,
        package: Icons.details.fontPackage,
        fontSize: 24.0,
        color: Colors.black
      ),
    );
```

Dart/Flutter source code is remarkably approachable, I highly recommend digging in a little!

Answer (score 0):

A better solution is to use `Transform.scale` like this:

```
 Transform.scale(
   scale: 0.5, // set your value here
   child: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.smartphone), onPressed: () {}),
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

***You can use ListTile it gives you a default space between text and Icons that would fit your needs***

```
ListTile(
         leading: Icon(Icons.add), //Here Is The Icon You Want To Use
         title: Text('GFG title',textScaleFactor: 1.5,), //Here Is The Text Also
         trailing: Icon(Icons.done),
         ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the following way:

```
InkWell(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
  onTap: () {},
  child: Container(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
    child: const Icon(Icons.favorite, color: Colors.red),
  ),
),
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAabJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
Container(
                      width: 30,
                      child: IconButton(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                      ),
                    ),
```

Answer (score -1):

Incase like me you came looking for an answer to the solution of an image instead of just an icon, I tried a mix of solutions here and arrived at a solution - 2024.

You need "tapTargetSize" of shrinkwrap to your IconButton style, need to also add the "padding" of zero and an empty "constraints".
Then you need to define your icon image width and height, should you still need a smaller padding, wrap the button with a container and add the a padding to it.

```
Container(
 padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
 decoration: BoxDecoration(
   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100)),
  child: IconButton(
    style: ButtonStyle(
    //This shrinks the auto padding
    tapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap, 
    ),
    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
    constraints: BoxConstraints(),
    onPressed: () {},
    icon: Image(
     width: 40,
     height: 40,
     image: AssetImage('your image link here'),
     ),
   ),
 ),
```

Answer (score -1):

```
IconButton(
   iconSize: 30,
   padding: EdgeInsets.zero, // make it zero
   constraints: const BoxConstraints(), // make box constraints empty
   style: const ButtonStyle(tapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap), // And this sstyle
   onPressed: () {},
   icon: const Icon(Icons.ac_unit_rounded),
)
```

Answer (score -9):

To show splash effect (ripple), use `InkResponse`:

```
InkResponse(
  Icon(Icons.volume_up),
  onTap: ...,
)
```

If needed, change icons size or add padding:

```
InkResponse(
  child: Padding(
    padding: ...,
    child: Icon(Icons.volume_up, size: ...),
  ),
  onTap: ...,
)
```

Comment: Nowhere in the question it is asked to show ripple effect!

Comment: @Ashish, IconButton implies having ripple effect. If you don't need ripple effect, you can just use GestureDetector. It's quite simple and shown in the top answer. My solution allows to remove padding but keep IconButton-like ripple