# Remove padding from Flutter PopupMenuButton

Tags: flutter, popupmenubutton

Any ideas how I can remove the huge padding from a Flutter PopupmenuButton? Something like a shrinkWrap or even an alternative widget that can use? It's ruining the alignment of my elements.

I tried setting the `padding` to 0 but no effect at all.

```
padding: EdgeInsets.all(0)
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Supplying `child` rather than `icon` will allow you to use a custom widget with any desired size/padding.

Note: `Icons.more_vert` carries its own padding, but any custom icon can be used to avoid that.

```
PopupMenuButton(
  child: Container(
    height: 36,
    width: 48,
    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
    child: Icon(
      Icons.more_vert,
    ),
  ),
  onSelected: (value) {},
  itemBuilder: (context) => [],
),
```

Comment: This answer helped. Thank you a lot.

Comment: This is what i was looking for. Thanku so much, u have saved my day of hard work

Comment: It works very well .. not even need to specify the height and the Width

Comment: here is my code it work for me...
PopupMenuButton<...>(
          child: Container(
            child: Icon(Icons.more_vert, ),
          ),
          onSelected: (... kValue) {
            
          },
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
            return ... ;
          }
      )

Answer (score 2):

You just have to supply an `Icon` component to its `child` property like below:

```
PopupMenuButton(
  child: Icon(
      Icons.more_vert,
    ),
  onSelected: (value) {},
  itemBuilder: (context) => [],
),
```

Answer (score 1):

If you carefully see the padding is not in the `PopupmenuButton` the padding there is coming from the `IconButton`.IconButton is a Material Design widget that follows the spec that tappable objects need to be at least 48px on each side. So it's better you create your own widget to reduce the padding.

A simple workaround to avoid it will be to use Icon wrapped with `GestureDetector`.

You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50381157/how-do-i-remove-flutter-iconbutton-big-padding) post for more details.

Answer (score 0):

From the Flutter Docs for the PopopMenuButton class,

> padding → EdgeInsetsGeometry
> Matches IconButton's 8 dps padding by **default**. In some cases, notably where this button appears as the trailing element of a list item, it's useful to be able to set the padding to zero.

You can change the padding to 0 as suggested by the docs.

Read More here - https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/PopupMenuButton-class.html

Answer (score 0):

A solution was provided but you have to edit non project files (PopupMenuItem class)

```
return InkWell(
      onTap: widget.enabled ? handleTap : null,
      child: Container(
        height: widget.height,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: _kHorizontalMenuPadding), // setting this to 0 worked 
        child: item,
      ),
    );
```

P.S: Not really recommended but still working

Comment: Thanks. It should work but, if one of the team mates does a `pub get` the code will not be there anymore.

Comment: Then you can try to create your own widget using it. So you'll have your own PopMenuItem (modified) and pub get won't be able to affect it anymore.

Comment: How can I find and copy this file to my project?

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Wrap it with SizedBox:

```
SizedBox(
  height:,
  child: Row(
    children: [
      PopupMenuButton(        
      )
    ],
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

put it  in a container work for me...

```
PopupMenuButton<...>(
          child: Container(
            child: Icon(Icons.more_vert, ),
          ),
          onSelected: (... kValue) {
            
          },
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
            return ... ;
          }
      )
```

Answer (score -1):

To remove Padding from PopUpMenu Button, Wrap it into Container and provide width as you want.

```
Container(
  width:20,
  child: PopupMenuButton( 
       // your Code is Here       
      ),
  )
```