# How to remove extra space from icons

Tags: flutter, dart

**Icon(ABC) has space at the top:**
[image]

Do icons have spaces by default?
Is there a way to remove spaces?

**Code:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const _MyApp());
}

class _MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const _MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: const [
            Text(
              "Demo1",
            ),
            Icon(
              Icons.abc,
              color: Colors.grey,
              size: 50,
            ),
            Text(
              "Demo2",
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,

Comment: The icon you are using have more spacing vertical than horizontal, so it is the space of that particular icon, not icon widgets itself (although icon do have some padding by default). You can change to another icon to see the effect.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove Flutter IconButton big padding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50381157/how-do-i-remove-flutter-iconbutton-big-padding)

Comment: @Stanly This question is not an IconButton, it is a Icon. I would like an answer with a Icon.

Answer (score 1):

- Set Row alignment to center

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/container.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: const [
            Text(
              "Demo1",
            ),
            Icon(
              Icons.abc,
              color: Colors.grey,
              size: 50,
            ),
            Text(
              "Demo2",
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You added explicitly more size to `icon` widget and your row `CrossAxisAlignment` is start you can need reduce icon size & set `CrossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center`

```
Row(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    children: const [
      Text("Demo1"),
      Icon(
        Icons.abc,
        color: Colors.grey,
        size: 50,
        //size: 35,
      ),
      Text("Demo2"),
    ],
)
```

[image]