# Remove click effect when IconButton() is clicked

Tags: flutter, dart

I am currently using the following code to create an `IconButton()` in Flutter:

```
IconButton(
  hoverColor: Colors.transparent,
  color: _tweenButton.value,
  icon: Icon(Icons.send),
  onPressed: () => _isComposing ? _handleSubmitted(_textController.text) : null,
)
```

Whenever I click on the icon button, there is a splash/click effect as depicted [in this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Rqc1.png). This widget is running inside `MaterialApp()` and `Scaffold()`.

How can I deactivate this visual effect?

Comment: [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49107295/how-to-disable-splash-highlight-of-flatbutton-in-flutter)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use this code:

```
IconButton(
 splashColor: Colors.transparent,
 highlightColor: Colors.transparent,  
 color: _tweenButton.value,
 icon: Icon(Icons.send),
 onPressed: () => _isComposing ? _handleSubmitted(_textController.text) : null,
)
```